# Cloudera - DnsResolutionMonitor throttling_logger Error

Tags: hdfs, cloudera

Facing frequent DNS resolution issues on the CDH cluster running in Azure VMs. We have dnsmasq installed on all the servers which resolve the DNS queries locally and same is verified from the DNS server.

**Error logs :**

(7 skipped) Failed to run DnsTest.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/monitor/host/dns_names.py", line 87, in collect_dns_metrics
    self._subprocess_with_timeout(args, self._poll_timeout)
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/monitor/host/dns_names.py", line 59, in _subprocess_with_timeout
    return subprocess_with_timeout(args, timeout)
  File "/opt/cloudera/cm-agent/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf/subprocess_timeout.py", line 95, in subprocess_with_timeout
    raise Exception("timeout with args %s" % args)
Exception: timeout with args ['/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java', '-classpath', '/opt/cloudera/cm/lib/agent-6.2.0.jar', 'com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest']